# Mismatch between native time inputs and Date locale

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, input

Native HTML time inputs [`<input type="time" />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#chrome_and_opera) take the 12/24 hour option based on the setting you have set on your OS. In my case I have a 12 hour system set.
I am now looking to display to the user which hour system he is using and was hoping to be able to do that with `toLocaleTimeString`, which I assumed had the same information that the `<input type="time" />` has about the hour system.

To my surprise `new Date().toLocaleTimeString()` returned the hour in a 24 hour system for me.
[image]
[image]

Comment: The term "locale" in "*toLocaleString*" means "language", not location. The misuse of "locale" to mean "language" seems to have its roots in ECMA-402, but it may have origins earlier than that. Anyhow, the formatting of *toLocale\** is based on the browser or system default language, not regional or other system settings (once upon a time called "preferences").

Comment: @RobG I see yeah. The documentation says it is indeed using the `Intl` API. But then it seems like the `<input type="time" />` accesses the time on the machine in some way that is inaccessible to javascript, because I cannot find a way to do it.

Comment: Browsers have access to system resources way beyond that revealed by ECMAScript APIs. Web APIs are usually written with concerns for privacy and security at the top of their agenda, so you aren't going to get access through a browser to many of the resources that might be available to a native program.

Comment: @RobG Yes, you are right. I was thinking the same thing and this seems to be the case. It is accessing system settings as a native app. I was hoping they would have some unified way of handling these input settings that is accessible to the enduser, because it makes sense to me, but I would have to find another way :|

Comment: Usually, attempting to customise date formats for the user's default language is a bad idea. Pages are written in a particular language, so formatting of dates, numbers, etc. should be in the language of the page, not some (more or less) randomised format. Far better to just use unambiguous formats (e.g. "February 4, 2023" vs "2/4/23").

Comment: @RobG My idea is not actually customizing anything. I just wanted to access the data itself about the type="time" field. I agree on the unambiguous format and will keep it in mind!